# Standard deviation cap crosses zero

Tags: standard-deviation, error, numpy

Let's say I have some reference data and some predicted data and I want to show the standard deviation of the mean absolute error. When I create error bar using numpy and matplotlib, errorbar crosses zero. Is it something normal? I believe this occurs due to fact that my std is higher than the mean.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x  = 3.5
ref_data = np.array([40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
pred_data = np.array([40.2, 51.4, 58.7, 71.2, 83.5, 71.6])


mae = np.mean(np.abs(ref_data - pred_data))
std = np.std(np.abs(ref_data - pred_data))


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.errorbar(x, mae, yerr=std, capsize=4, marker='o', color='crimson')

plt.show()
```

and output
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing exactly "wrong" with this, you're showing the estimated mean absolute error and that the estimated standard deviation of the absolute errors is larger than the estimated mean absolute error.

But, you might've been intending to construct a confidence interval for the MAE instead. A typical Stat 100 approach would be to construct a 95% confidence interval as

$$
\text{MAE} \pm 1.96\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}
$$

Where $\text{MAE}$ is the estimated mean absolute error, $1.96$ comes from the standard normal distribution, $s$ is the estimated standard deviation, and $n$ is the total sample size. This would lead to $(-1.25,9.91)$ as the 95% confidence interval.

But that still includes negative values! Why doesn't this work? The naive Stat 100 approach assumes that the quantity being estimated is approximately normally distributed. This is the case in many situations, for example if you're estimating the mean and $n$ is moderately large. But the approximation does not work here, $n = 6$ is too small.

Instead we could try a numeric method called the bootstrap. We re-sample the data with replacement many times and estimate the mean absolute error in each dataset. We sort those values from smallest to largest, and take the 2.5% and 97.5% largest value as the bounds of the confidence interval. That leads to $(0.92, 10.05)$ as an estimate of the 95% confidence interval. This is likely still a poor estimate, since there are only 6 data points, but at least it excludes values we know to be impossible.